# CRM 2011 JavaScript IDE

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking for some sort of tool which does not necessarily need to be CRM specific, rather i am just looking for some sort of javascript compiler which will detect basic syntactic issues ahead of time.

Visual Studio seems to ignore things like:

```js
var fetchXml = new String();
fetchxml = "fetchstring";
```

I had a look at apanta studio 3 which seemed pretty cool but it did not pick up basic syntactic issues like i'd hoped for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [JSLint](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/). It's a plugin for VS that detects possible issues ahead of time. You can set it up to interpret your files on save, build, etc.